# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in UserStepsController#update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used Wicked gem to create a multistep form. First step is sign up with email name and password, second step would be address for now containing only the street. Here is my address.html.erb

```
    <%= form_for @user, url: wizard_path do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :street %>
        <%= f.text_area :street %>
    </div>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

  <% end %>
```

I permitted street and other params in the UsersController:

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController

      def index
        @users = User.all
      end

      def new
        @user = User.new
      end


      def create
        @user = User.new(params[:user])
        if @user.save
          session[:user_id] = @user.id
          redirect_to user_steps_path
        else
          render :new

   end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :first_name, :last_name, :street, :house_number, :city, :zip_code)
  end

end
```

I am getting the error mentioned in the title. And these are the params. It basically gets the street, but somhow assignes id to address?

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"ZOkBaqFUdFj47iI8vB0D4PI26ZsgEKasqbzvVM2ry4Z3e+AsYMh0yRSuUoZF5zbJ3SzAkPShI0sjaZOgh0yXRw==",
 "user"=>{"street"=>"jef b"},
 "commit"=>"Update User",
 "id"=>"address"}
```

What is happening and how to correct it? Here is UserSteprController:

```
class UserStepsController < ApplicationController
    include Wicked::Wizard
    steps :address


    def show
      @user = current_user
      render_wizard
    end


    def update
      @user = current_user
      @user.attributes = params[:user]
      render_wizard @user
    end

    private

    def redirect_to_finish_wizard
      new_user_profile_path(current_user.id)
    end

end
```

Second line in the update action is wrong: @user.attributes = params[:user]
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting a `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` is that you are passing an unfiltered hash from the params to your model.

```
@user.attributes = params[:user]
```

Is pretty much a textbook example of a mass assignment vulnerability which allows a malicious user to assign any attribute they want like for example `admin: true`. Fortunately Rails has had built in mass-assignment protection since Rails 4 which stopped you from inflicting the vulnerability on your app.

You want to use `update` or `update_attributes` instead of the setter and pass it your filtered parameters instead.

```
@user.update_attributes(user_params)
```

Comment: I solved it similary, however I had to define user_params again in this controller. It won't get the out of users. Is that right? Or where is the mistake?

Comment: `user_params` is just a plain old instance method. If you want to share it between multiple controllers you can do it either through inheritance or by using a concern (a module mixin).